# CakePHP 3.x - How to configure the Cache-Control header for image assets?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can I turn on the cache settings in my CakePHP 3.x. Ideally, I would like to have the cache turn on only for images (not for CSS or JS files)

At this moment the header of my website is:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
```

I tried to write:

```
   Cache::enable(); in initialize() function of my AppController
```

but it did not work. Could you please suggest me the correct settings?

EDIT calling if(Cache::enabled()) results true - why I have the above headers is such situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**HTTP caching**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) and CakePHP's [**`\Cake\Cache\Cache` class**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/caching.html) have nothing to do with each other, the latter is used for server side caching of application data, such as model schemas, translations, query results, etc.

Unless your assets do live in a plugin and you haven't [**symlinked/copied them into your application's webroot folder**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/plugin-shell.html#plugin-assets) (which you *should* do), assets are served by the webserver without (Cake)PHP being involved, ie you'll have to configure your server accordingly. Refer to the documentation of the server software that you are using, or the many questions on this topic that can be found here on StackOverflow.

A small example for Apache, using the [**`Header` directive**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html) in for example a `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    # ...
</FilesMatch>
```